# Shortest way to check for age filter in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, filter

I am trying to check for people in a certain range - let lb-lowerbound and ub-upper bound corresponding for e.g. age group with lb=18 and ub=24 meaning I am trying to filter out the people aged between 18 and 24.Also Datetime field in database for date of birth is nullable.I have this code -

```
var users=from e in employee
          where e.DOB.HasValue && ((DateTime.Now.Year - e.DOB.Value.Year)) >= lb) 
          && ((DateTime.Now.Year - e.DOB.Value.Year) <= ub)
          select e;
```

but this is only checks with the year how do I use the month and find out the actual age and filter out the users according to their age ? Thanks everyone for their help.

Comment: @the_drow: TimeSpan is inappropriate for an imprecise duration such as "18 years" or "3 months". That's why the TimeSpan structure only has properties as far as "days". (Even that's somewhat spurious IMO.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Firstly, that query is incorrect in terms of times during the year - you could be 17 and still counted as 18, for example - very few people born in 1993 are 18 as of today (January 17th 2011). Also, it's computing `DateTime.Now` multiple times, which means the year could vary *while the query is executing*.

Finally, if you've just got a single `where` clause and your `select` clause is a no-op, it's generally simpler to use the extension method syntax rather than a query expression.

I would suggest:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime min = today.AddYears(-ub);
DateTime max = today.AddYears(-lb);

var years = employee.Where(e => e.DOB != null && e.DOB >= min && e.DOB <= max);
```

EDIT: To be clearer, for a maximum age of (say) 10, that means you want to exclude anyone whose date of birth was *11* years ago or more, so you'd write:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime min = today.AddYears(-(maxAge + 1));
DateTime max = today.AddYears(-minAge);

var years = employee.Where(e => e.DOB != null && e.DOB > min && e.DOB <= max);
```

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Would you really say that your code is more readable then mine? It took me a second to figure out that AddYears is substracting (and that's kind of microsoft's fault) but still, don't you prefer reading queries?

Comment: @the_drow: Well my code will compile... I suspect yours won't :) You can't get a number of years from a TimeSpan, as the duration of a year changes depending on the date and year. Moreover, I think it makes sense to work out the boundaries *once* and then apply them universally.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: So Timespan cannot consider the DateTimes it is consisted of?

Comment: @the_drow: It *doesn't* consist of DateTimes. It's a number of ticks, that's all.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Yeh figured this out myself. It's a shame though.

Comment: @the_drow: Well, it makes sense that there's a type like TimeSpan. Maybe there should also be an Interval type though. (Noda Time has Period, Duration and Interval... with possibly LocalInterval at some point too.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet thanks..but there is a user with dob=12/27/66 and hence his age is 44...and the min is 1/17/1967 while max is 1/17/1976...so he should fall in 35-44 category but is falling into 45-54..do you know how could i fix it ?

Comment: Actually he is not falling in any category..so for lb=35 and ub=44..i have min=1/17/1967 and max=1/17/1976...while for lb=45 and ub=54...min=1/17/1957 and max=1/17/1966

Comment: @Misnomer: You need to have the upper bound of one group the same as the lower bound of the other - and probably make one of the conditions exclusive. Instead of thinking in terms of age, think in terms of "born at least X years ago today" or "born at most Y years ago today". Will edit to clarify.

Comment: Thanks that worked..should have occurred to me..i actually had it that way earlier then moved away from it..thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick (Not tested):

```
var users = from e in employee
            where e.DOB.HasValue && (DateTime.Today - e.DOB.Value.Date) >= min.Date 
                  && e.DOB.Date <= max.Date
            select e;
```

Comment: What are the types of min and max here? (It looks like `min` would be an `int` and `max` would be a DateTime?`.) And where are you getting the Years property from?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Sorry, did not compile my code and warned about it. I will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create an Age model and compare ages rather than mess around with dates?

```
public class Age
{
    private readonly DateTime dob;

    public Age(DateTime dob)
    {
        this.dob = dob;           
    }

    public int Value
    {
        get { return this.CalculateAge(this.dob); }
    }

    private int CalculateAge(DateTime dob)
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        int age = today.Year - dob.Year;
        if (today.Month < dob.Month || (today.Month == dob.Month && today.Day < dob.Day))
            age--;
        return age;
    }
}
```

Then use linq to query for min and max ages. You would put Age as a property in your employee model. When you build your employee you would call use the Age class to calculate the age. Your linq would then look like this:

```
var years = employee.Where(e.Age >= min && e.Age <= max);
```