# LINQ to Entities: Age calculation in a LINQ query causes "Method cannot be translated into a store expression"

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-entities

Using LINQ to Entities, I need to get records from a PersonTable WHERE Age is between AgesFrom and AgesTo. The problem is, I need to calculate their Age from a DateOfBirth and a specific DateToCalculate, both stored in the database.

eg.
PersonTable: DateOfBirth=01/04/1972, DateToCalculateAge=25/12/2011

```
.Where(0 < o.FormDate.AddYears(-agesFrom).CompareTo(o.FormDate.Subtract(o.Person.DateOfBirth)) &&
       0 > o.FormDate.AddYears(-agesTo).CompareTo(o.FormDate.Subtract(o.Person.DateOfBirth));
// ----------------------- OR ------------------------
.Where(agesFrom <= CalculateAge(o.Person.DateOfBirth.Value, o.FormDate) &&
       agesTo >= CalculateAge(o.Person.DateOfBirth.Value, o.FormDate);
```

For my provided code, I get the following Exception: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddYears(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

I understand that once LINQ passes the Query over to the db, the method(s) I were trying to use could not be translated. Is there a work around for this? I could filter after hitting the database, but want to avoid that sort of bottle neck. I also thought of adding a sql function to do this calculation for me, but want to exhaust the LINQ possibilities first.

A nice post here details how it is better to do the age calculation before the query:
[Shortest way to check for age filter in LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715155/shortest-way-to-check-for-age-filter-in-linq) However in my situation, I am not calculating age from DateTime.Now, but rather age from a date in the db.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are using LINQ to Entities, the preferred solution is to utilize the methods defined in [`System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.aspx) (***update for EF version 6:*** use [`DbFunctions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.aspx) instead) and the query surface will translate them into SQL successfully. In this case you want to take e.g. this:

```
o.FormDate.AddYears(-agesFrom)
          .CompareTo(o.FormDate.Subtract(o.Person.DateOfBirth))
```

and convert it to something like

```
EntityFunctions.DiffMinutes(
    EntityFunctions.AddYears(o.FormDate, -agesFrom),
    EntityFunctions.AddSeconds(
        o.FormDate, 
        EntityFunctions.DiffSeconds(o.FormDate, o.Person.DateOfBirth)
    )
)
```

I 'm not sure if the above is actually correct as it stands though because it really hurts my eyes.

Comment: Thanks! Those EntityFunctions saved me a lot of time and trouble.

Comment: EntityFunctions.AddYears is now obsolete - the suggested alternative is:  System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddYears   ...which does the same thing.

Comment: EntityFunctions / DbFunctions are not testable in unit tests

Answer (score 0):

You can't use those methods in LINQ to Entities. But, if the query is done in memory, you can. Try using a `.ToList()` before the `.Where`:

```
.ToList().Where(0 < o.FormDate.AddYears(-agesFrom)
         .CompareTo(o.FormDate.Subtract(o.Person.DateOfBirth)) && 0 > o.FormDate.AddYears(-agesTo)
         .CompareTo(o.FormDate.Subtract(o.Person.DateOfBirth));
```

or

```
.ToList().Where(agesFrom <= CalculateAge(o.Person.DateOfBirth.Value, o.FormDate) 
          && agesTo >= CalculateAge(o.Person.DateOfBirth.Value, o.FormDate);
```

This way the `.ToList()` will bring the query to memory and you will be able to use the methods.

It's performance will be hurt if you have a huge database, but it will work.

Comment: am trying to avoid bringing it into memory as there are potentially ... many results :)