# Only get entries from DB matching the current week

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to get the entries from the database, where `table.Date.WeekDayThing = DateTime.Now.WeekDayThing` (refer below for method), but I get the error

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32
>   GetIso8601WeekOfYear(System.DateTime)' method, and this method cannot
>   be translated into a store expression.

**LINQ Query**

```
var dbHours = DAO.Instance.HourRegistration
    .Where(x => x.Login_ID == logId && x.Cust_ID == custId && GetIso8601WeekOfYear(x.Date) == GetIso8601WeekOfYear(DateTime.Now))
    .Include(x => x.Customer)
    .ToList();
```

**Method GetIso8601WeekOfYear(DateTime time)**

```
public int GetIso8601WeekOfYear(DateTime time)
    {
        // Seriously cheat.  If its Monday, Tuesday or Wednesday, then it'll 
        // be the same week# as whatever Thursday, Friday or Saturday are,
        // and we always get those right
        DayOfWeek day = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetDayOfWeek(time);
        if (day >= DayOfWeek.Monday && day <= DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
        {
            time = time.AddDays(3);
        }

        // Return the week of our adjusted day
        return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(time, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
    }
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to fetch the data, and apply the week filter after that:

```
var dbHours = DAO.Instance.HourRegistration
    .Where(x => x.Login_ID == logId && x.Cust_ID == custId)
    .Include(x => x.Customer)
    .ToList()
    .Where(x => GetIso8601WeekOfYear(x.Date) == GetIso8601WeekOfYear(DateTime.Now));
```

If you think this will bring back too many results you can filter for example to only bring back last 7 days of data which will guarantee the current week is there.

The other option is to re-write your function into EntityFunctions like described here: [LINQ to Entities: Age calculation in a LINQ query causes "Method cannot be translated into a store expression"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601701/linq-to-entities-age-calculation-in-a-linq-query-causes-method-cannot-be-trans)

Comment: @Detilium, it will never work like you write it, GetIso8601WeekOfYear cannot be run against SQL Server. You can run the query like suggested by Horia but take care of scalability because the suggested query retrieve all the data of all the weeks in memory (also solving Customer relationship) then filter for the actual week so usually it fetches 52/2 = 26 times the records needed (at the end of year 52 times).

Comment: That's why I said, to filter the data to only bring back last 7 days with a condition like `&& x.Date >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7)` in the first `Where`.

Comment: Ading the `&& x.Date >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)` gives the same error as my initial question

Comment: Oh, ok, maybe you can declare de 7 days ago into a variable, and use the variable instead of the function.

Answer (score 0):

In LINQ for EF you can use only supported functions that are canonical functions (the only that should be supported by all ef providers) or functions supported by your provider (SQL Server).

In this cases you have 2 different approaches: you can write a stored procedure to solve all the query and then map it to EF or you can explode the query using only the supported functions.

DateTime Canonical functions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738563(v=vs.100).aspx

SQL Server EF provider functions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb399545(v=vs.100).aspx

In your case the right function is DatePart (mixed with some checks).

**EDIT**

There is always the solution to materialize the query "early" (put a ToList early then work in memory) but this means that you fetch more data than you need.

**EDIT2**

SQL Server DATEPART has already the way to get the week using ISO standard. Your LINQ query should be this (but I did not try it).

```
.Where(x => x.Login_ID == logId && x.Cust_ID == custId && SqlFunctions.DatePart("ISO_WEEK", x.Date) == SqlFunctions.DatePart(DateTime.Now))
```

Reference are the links above and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

Comment: Could you give an example of the DATEPART in my context?

Comment: What namespace is the Sqlserver? VS gives me 2 options: Microsoft.SqlServer, and System.Data.Entity.SqlServer?

Comment: System.Data.Entity.SqlServer

Comment: `The type or namespace 'DATEPART' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer'`?

Comment: Sorry, DATEPART is the corresponding SQL Server function. In LINQ you need to use DatePart. Already fixed in answer...

Comment: I fixed it in the answer. I know how they works but I don't use them because the app will depends on SQL Server (will work only on it).